# Magento 2 : Phpunit test for catalog module, mock error for setExtensionAttributes()

Tags: magento2, phpunit

Magento 2 phpunit test for catalog module error display below:

I want to run test for catalog model folder files,

Run phptest using command like:

```
var/www/html/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit$ php phpunit /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/
```

Result for above command display error:

```
Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Model\CustomOptions\CustomOptionProcessorTest::testConvertToBuyRequest
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: Cannot mock Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface::setExtensionAttributes() because a class or interface used in the signature is not loaded
```

i am using magento catalog native module for phpunit test and error are display after run test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you run this command line without phpunit.xml.dist:

Try to use this command line:

`var/www/html/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit$ php phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/`

I've included here explicit declaration of phpunit config file
`-c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist`.

Be sure that you always include a phpunit config file for appropriate tests, when invoke them. It's applicable for unit tests , integration tests, etc., cause phpunit config files contains code, that set up a test environment.